# SonataAdminBundle: What is the process of persisting and retrieving data?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I tried to find some documents that describes the process of persisting and retrieving data of `SonataAdminBundle` because when I have some problems, it's always difficult for me to figure it out what's going on if I don't know its mechanism. For example,

```
// DemoBundle\Administrator\UserAdmin
class UserAdmin extends Admin
{

    // Fields to be shown on create/edit forms
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'Name'))
            ->add('lastName', 'text', array('label' => 'Last name'))
            ->add('email') 
            ->add('username')
            ->add('password')
            ->add('rolesCollection','entity',array(
            'class' => 'DemoBundle:Role',
            'property'=>'name',
            'expanded' => true,
            'compound' => true,
            'multiple' => true,
            'by_reference' => false
        ))
        ));
     }
}
```

When I click on `Update` button:
Which methods called by `SonataAdminBundle` to persist the user and role? 
Which methods called by `SonataAdminBundle` to show the user and role data after persisting?

Answer (score 0):

There are basicly 2 important files used in the process in my opinion. First of all you have the "BaseAdmin" class which is `Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin.php`. You'll always extend your entity admin class from that one (See your own code...) and secondly you got the "controller" which is `Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController.php` which will be the controller handling all the CRUD actions. You can easily overwrite that one and use your custom CRUD controller for your entity. For more info on this subject take a look [here](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/architecture.html) (especially [4.1](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/architecture.html#the-admin-class) and [4.2](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/architecture.html#crudcontroller)) Hope that answers your question.